# Play two consecutive haptics on Apple Watch, second one does not fire

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, haptic-feedback

Trying to have a second haptic fire after a first one. However, for some reason the second one does not fire. I added DispatchQueue function to see if it was because they were firing so close together, but it still does not work.

```
        WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(WKHapticType.stop)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(WKHapticType.notification)
        }
```

Comment: `.now() + 1` is in 1 nanosecond after the first one, so they are still too close to each other. Try `.now() + .milliseconds(N)` with different Ns, so offset will be bigger

Comment: @abjurato I tried your recommendation with `.milliseconds(3000)` Apparently, the second haptic (.notification) only plays while I have the watch awake in the foreground, but not in the background (when screen is off).

Comment: "By default, you cannot play haptic feedback in the background. The only exception are apps with an active workout session." - 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/1628128-playhaptic

Comment: @abjurato my app is a workout app, and the haptic is playing during the active workout session.